# ActiveAdmin with Rails 4: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am new to rails and building my first web application using version 4.2.4.

I am trying to install the [activeadmin](https://rubygems.org/gems/activeadmin) gem using

```
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 0.6.6'
```

However, when I run bundle install I get an error which says:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (= 4.2.4)

  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (~> 0.6.6) ruby depends on
      rails (< 4, >= 3.0.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.2.4) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Is this suggesting that I need to go down a version of rails in order to make this gem work or can I keep 4.2.4 and use the suggested bundle update method without causing any issues with my app and other gems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of activeadmin that your Gemfile specifies does not support Rails 4.  From [the readme](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/f7483e3b8fcd74437b03c18fb658dac62a9fc62e/README.md):

> We're currently working on 1.0.0, which as far as dependencies, moves
>   us from meta_search to Ransack and adds Rails 4 & 5 support.
>
> You can get it by tracking master:
>
> ```
> gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
> ```
>
> Or you can using rubygems:
>
> ```
> gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre2'
> ```

Change your Gemfile as shown, and then run `bundle install`

Comment: really appreciate that wayne. I will try the ruby gems code you furnished now and revert back in a minute on the answer

Comment: wayne you are a legend. it worked. thank you for helping me. regards